# How to get context of what Object corresponds to a certain UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, interface-builder

Below you can find an image of a UITableViewCell subclass that I've created. Each cell corresponds to a game that is played between two contestants, and has a winner, defined by the selected control (that in the editor says "first" and "second"). If this winner value is changed, I want to update that game's information and store it in Core Data. The problem is that when I create an IBAction connection to my storyboard, and it gets triggered when the winner is changed, it has no context or knowledge of what game it belongs to, and therefore I can't figure out which game to update the winner of.

How do I get context of the game that was acted on in this IBAction `winnerChanged()` method? Could I somehow use the superView or superClass of the UISegmentedControl to get more information about the UITableViewCell as a whole?

```swift
@IBAction func winnerChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        os_log("Saving games because winner was changed", type: .debug)
        // need to know what game to change the winner of here
        self.allGames.forEach({ updateOrCreateGame(game: $0) })
    }
```

Here's my code for my UITableViewCell subclass:

```swift
class ConferenceResultsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var gameWinnerControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var confidenceTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var confidenceAverageAllUsersLabel: UILabel!

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you create such `@IBAction`s right inside the cell. From your question, I assume that the method `@IBAction func winnerChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl)` defined somewhere in your controller.

It would be much easier and also resolve your question if you create a dedicated class for your cell with an implementation of that method.
This will allow you to hook your cell with a concrete CoreData's object (through identifier in an example below). All you need to do is to call `setup` method somewhere from `cellForRow` of your controller/data source.

```
final class MatchCell: UITableViewCell {

   @IBAction func winnerChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
      ...
   }

   func setup(with match: Match) {
      self.matchId = mathc.id
      ...
   }

}
```

if you still need that `updateOrCreateGame` method inside your controller you can pass a callback `onUpdateRequested: (Match) -> Void` in `setup` method and call that callback from `winnerChanged` method.

Comment: What do you mean by "This will allow you to hook your cell with a concrete CoreData's object"? I have a dedicated ViewCell subclass, I'll post that code in my question.

Comment: in that case, you can store object's identifier directly inside the cell

Comment: I don't have a game identifier currently. Are you saying I should create one? If I do create one, how would I use it to solve my problem?

Comment: well, you can also store the whole game object in a cell. it's not an ideal approach, but it would work in a simple case as yours

Comment: if you got an identifier you could search through your `allGames` array for an object with that identifier

Comment: Where would I set the game's identifier? In `tableView(cellForRowAt:)` in my ViewController?

Comment: yes, if you're setting up your cell in that method. but it also a good idea to have some kind of `setup(` method inside your cell that will do all the work (setting your labels, ref to object, etc). that'll keep your controller/data source clean form that stuff

Comment: Okay, with your suggestion I placed a game object in each cell in a setup method. Then I was able to reference it like this: `let viewcell = sender.superview?.superview as? ConferenceResultsTableViewCell;
        guard viewcell != nil else {
            os_log("viewcell is nil in winnerChanged in ConferenceResultsTableViewController", type: .debug);
            return;
        }
        guard let game = viewcell?.game else {};`I like this method. Thanks for your help!

Comment: the point is to put your `winnerChanged` method inside cell's subclass, so it could access object without these superclass manipulations